# How to get a MSAL access token for SharePoint Online in a federated environment the non-interactive way in a non-interactive .Net console app?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-msal, federated-identity

The task as simple as to have a scheduled .NET console app which will download a file from SharePoint Online on a regular basis using AD domain user account.
If I use recommended way

```
var token = publicApplication.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

I'm getting

> UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

What does it mean? Which URI, hostname? Should I override something somewhere or add some special parameter?
I've googled thru this stuff a lot, and I have no idea where to look further, any advice will be appreciated.

P.S. I have no permissions to do anything on SharePoint side, I'm not a SP admin. I just have access to specific folder on the site from which I'm downloading the file. And also I have a code which works interactively:

```
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        var scopes = new string[] { "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/.default" };
        var options = new PublicClientApplicationOptions()
        {
            TenantId = "tenant.com",
            ClientId = "{872cd9fa-d31f-45e0-9eab-6e460a02d1f1}",//known Visual Studio Id
        };
        var publicApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(options).Build();
        var token = publicApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithLoginHint("name.surname@tenant.com").ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

But it shows a browser window [image: Taking you to your organisation's sign-in page...]

No questions asked, pop-up disappear, and I get the token which is used further to download a file from SPOnline using /_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(' stuff.

So just run the app, see the popup, get the file downloaded. No interaction needed.
But this approach doesn't work if I put this routine really non-interactive:

> Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the non-interactive way is only possible using tenant-side registered application. Implemented using certificate authentication.
But surprisingly the token obtained by ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder doesn't work the way I wanted/expected (scopes/user impersonation issues). So now we use Graph client approach.
This is the only way which works for me (.NetFramework 4.7.2):

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
//...
        static async Task GetFile(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string fileName2get)
        {
            var fileitem = graphClient
                .Sites["SiteGuidYouMayGetBy /sites/[your site name]/_api/site/id"]
                .Drives["CrazyLongDriveIdYouMayGetByEnumeratingDrivesHere"]
                .Root
                .ItemWithPath($"/Path To The File starting from Drive Root/{fileName2get}")
                .Content
                .Request().GetResponseAsync();
            var stream = fileitem.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create($"C:/Temp/{fileName2get}"))
            {
                await stream.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
```